# How to interpret the output of predict() in R survival package?

Tags: r, prediction, survival

Recently I'm using R survival package to try to predict the probability of people going to churn. I found some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408862/how-to-predict-survival-probabilities-in-r) on stack overflow and also tried that to my own data. Here is my prediction model and output:

```
> Status_by_Time <- Surv(time = Duration, event = Gift_Status_ind)
> model.fit2 <- survreg(Status_by_Time ~ Age
                + Gender_ind 
                + Fundraiser_ind
                + Monthly.Recurring.Amount
                + Frequency_ind
                + Monthly.first.gift.amount
                + Monthly.last.gift.amount
                #+ Duration
                #+ Saved.
                + Upgrade.first.time
                + Upgrade.second.time,
                dist = "logistic"
)

> summary(model.fit2)
                            Value Std. Error      z         p
(Intercept)                81.525    1.46725  55.56  0.00e+00
Age                         0.156    0.01889   8.27  1.33e-16
Gender_ind2                 2.278    0.55955   4.07  4.68e-05
Gender_ind3                -9.514    1.09689  -8.67  4.18e-18
Fundraiser_ind2            -8.798    0.69303 -12.70  6.25e-37
Fundraiser_ind3             4.028    0.90970   4.43  9.52e-06
Monthly.Recurring.Amount   -1.211    0.04856 -24.95 2.39e-137
Frequency_ind2            257.319    0.00000    Inf  0.00e+00
Frequency_ind3              8.562    2.71423   3.15  1.61e-03
Frequency_ind4            -89.067    1.39379 -63.90  0.00e+00
Monthly.first.gift.amount  -2.538    0.03721 -68.22  0.00e+00
Monthly.last.gift.amount    1.827    0.04981  36.67 2.38e-294
Upgrade.first.time          6.467    0.82381   7.85  4.15e-15
Upgrade.second.time        10.849    2.72927   3.98  7.04e-05
Log(scale)                  2.869    0.00841 341.02  0.00e+00

Scale= 17.6 

Logistic distribution
Loglik(model)= -51841.8   Loglik(intercept only)= -55404
Chisq= 7124.45 on 13 degrees of freedom, p= 0 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 8 
n= 18097 

> predicted.values <- predict(model.fit2, newdata = churn.df.trim, type = "quantile", p = (1:9)/10) # 10 times event???
> head(predicted.values)
            [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]
 [1,]   2.219425 16.513993 26.01508 33.80343 40.95072 48.09800 55.88635 65.38744 79.68201
 [2,]  11.088257 25.382825 34.88392 42.67227 49.81955 56.96683 64.75518 74.25627 88.55084
 [3,] -11.996590  2.297977 11.79907 19.58742 26.73470 33.88198 41.67033 51.17143 65.46599
 [4,]   5.456971 19.751539 29.25263 37.04098 44.18826 51.33555 59.12390 68.62499 82.91955
 [5,]  19.690749 33.985316 43.48641 51.27476 58.42204 65.56932 73.35767 82.85876 97.15333
 [6,]  -8.187469  6.107099 15.60819 23.39654 30.54382 37.69111 45.47946 54.98055 69.27511
```

I reckon all these numbers are not probabilities. Is there some way to interpret these numbers or turn them into probabilities? Also if I use `p = (1:9)/10` does that mean I'm calculating the probability for the next 9 or 10 period?

Much appreciate if someone could give me a straight forward explanation (none academic one).

Comment: There is no type="quantile" in `predict.coxph`. You need to describe the functions used in creating `model.fit2`.

Comment: To expand upon @BondedDust's comment, would you please post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Also, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)). As written, I'm not sure anybody can answer your question unless they are an expert on the functions you're using. There's simply not enough context.

Comment: Hi @RichardErickson I have added some extra code to describe my quesion (the model I use and the summary of my model). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi @DWin, the function I use is not `predict.coxph`. It is `predict.survreg` and I think we can choose `type = "quantile" ` then in there. I have also added some new code so you can know where `model.fit2` comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fitting an Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) model, so all the interpretation should be made in light of this model. I must admit I am have never used this type of models, but perhaps this can help. The model is described as
$$\log(T) = \mu_0 - X\beta + \epsilon$$
This means that the prediction is of the answer on the left-hand side. 
In `?predict.survreg`, for `type` it says that:

> This can be on the original scale of the data (response), the linear
>   predictor ("linear", with "lp" as an allowed abbreviation), a
>   predicted quantile on the original scale of the data ("quantile"), a
>   quantile on the linear predictor scale ("uquantile"), or the matrix of
>   terms for the linear predictor ("terms"). At this time "link" and
>   linear predictor ("lp") are identical.

Meaning that with the specification that you made you get quantiles of the prediction on the time-scale. With $p=0.1$ for example, you get the $t$ for which
$$P(T\leq t)=0.1$$

Then the question would be why you get negative predictions for some of the quantiles, which seems unreasonable. I think this has something to do with the logistic assumption.

Comment: Hi @Theodor so here is my understanding:   my `prediction.value` is the time value of the probability reaching 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc? Is that correct?

Comment: The quantile is the other way round: value of time for which the probability is 0.1, 0.2, etc. For example with 0.5, you would get the median survival time.

Answer (score 1):

Your predict() call ends up calling predict.survreg() in the background and if you look at the documentation for that (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/predict.survreg.html) it appears that you may want to select the argument type="response" instead of "quantile" to get a more understandable output?